# Update panel does not respond to button event

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

Is there any problem with my code?
update panel does not show requested label after button click

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatesPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" OnUnload="UpdatePanel_UnLoad">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUpdateSavedSuccess" Text=" Changes Saved Successfully :) " runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                        Font-Names="Comic Sans MS" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="#00CC00" Visible="false"/><br />

                    <asp:Label ID="lblUpdateSavedFailed" Text=" Something Went worng :( " runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                        Font-Names="Comic Sans MS" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false"/><br />

                    <asp:Label ID="lblUpdateNoChanges" Text=" There is now changes :| " runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                        Font-Names="Comic Sans MS" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="#0099FF" Visible="False"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateInfo" runat="server" Text ="Save Changes" OnClick="btnUpdateInfo_Click"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="deleteUser" runat="server" Text="Delete User" Width="118px" OnClick="deleteUser_Click" />

                    <br /><br />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

my button event:

```
    protected void btnUpdateInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                lblUpdateSavedSuccess.Visible = true;
                lblUpdateSavedFailed.Visible = false;
                lblUpdateNoChanges.Visible = false;
    }
```

I have to use OnUnload="UpdatePanel_UnLoad" in my update panel because while complie my work I have an exception releated to unregister updatePanel.

Comment: Tested your code and it works fine (assuming you have a `ScriptManager` somewhere). Maybe the problem is in `UpdatePanel_UnLoad`

Comment: I dont know why its not working. I have ScriptManager inside my form. without UpdatePanel_UnLoad thorwn exception releated to unregister updatePanel.

Comment: Strip down your code until that error is solved. Begin with trying to get the update panel to work without ` UpdateMode="Conditional"` and `OnUnload="UpdatePanel_UnLoad"`

Comment: I tried to this this in all possiable vesions and its still doesnt work

Comment: What happens when you try a second updatepanel somewhere with a simple Label update?

Comment: I've read somewehere that the line `<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>` in the Web.Config could also interfere with the UpdatePanel. As Dennis Wessels also points out it is working on his machine also thus the problem is related to your project itself. Like something in the Web.Config or other pieces of code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried replicating your problem on my side but everything is working fine.Usually if there are issues with the AJAX controls it's because you have another java script library added to the page which conflicts with the AJAX scrits.You can confirm this by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+J` in Google chrome while your web page is running and inspecting the browser console.

I've also had issues in the past where the js scripts were not being loaded properly for AJAX and adding `EnableCdn="true"` to the ScriptManager fixed the probem:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableCdn="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Hope this helps you in fixing your issue.